# Showing that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n-f_{n+1}$ converges normally if $f_n$ converges normally

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

A function sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges normally in an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ to the limit function $f$.  Show that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(f_n-f_{n+1})$ converges normally in $U$ and identify the sum.

First we consider the following $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n-f_{n+1}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n+1}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}s_n - s_{n+1}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}-(s_{n+1} - s_{n})$$ where $s_n$ denotes the partial sums.

I'm a bit stuck trying to push forward on why this sum converges normally and what it converges to.

Comment: You are given that the **sequence** $f_n$ converges normally.  That doesn't say that the **series** $\sum_n f_n$ converges normally.

Comment: Hint: when you separated the two sums try and subtract one from the other. You're not left with much afterwards.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Am I thinking about this incorrectly by looking at the partial sums?

Comment: @Marc If I subtract the partial sum I'm left with the $n+1$ term.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: abet: you are left with one other term too

Comment: @Henry what do you mean?

Comment: You are left with $f_0$ and the limit of the $f_n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the partial sum:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m}f_n-f_{n+1}$$ $$=(f_1-f_2)+(f_2-f_3)+(f_3-f_4)+\cdots+(f_{m-1}-f_m)+(f_m-f_{m+1})$$ $$= f_1-f_{m+1}$$ and then take the limit as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: So this leaves us with $f_1-f$.  How does this show normal convergence of the series?

Comment: @abet because $f$ converges, as *STATED*

Comment: Would it be correct to say that because $\lim\limits_{m\to \infty}s_m=f_1-f$. where $f_{m+1} \to f$ normally we know that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(f_n-f_{n+1})$ converges normally?

Comment: abet: yes, and we know it converges to $f_1-f$